# Install4j - buttons appearance

Tags: java, install4j

Is there any way how to change size of '`Finish`' button in `Install4j`.
In style definition, there is a control button and in its initialization script I'm trying:

```
configurationObject.setSize(150,80);
configurationObject.setToolTipText("Install application");
```

SetSize do nothing. But tooltip is set correctly. Is any problem with my code? Or are there any attributes which cannot be set by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a layout manager at work, so calling `setSize` only has a temporary effect.

Try

```
configurationObject.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 200));
```

instead.

Comment: setPrefferedSize did't work for me. But I have tried setMinimumSize() and it works well. Thanks Ingo for your advice.

Comment: Indeed, the install4j runtime calls `setPreferredSize` on the button itself. I've updated the answer.